# how to generate xml like this format in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<resource>
<string>a</string><--comment here-->
<string>b</string>
</resource>
```

My project need to generate xml in above way .
I'am using php base library DOMDocument to generate this.

if I use **formatOutput=true** ,that would be

```
<resource>
<string>a</string>
<--comment-->
<string>b</string>
</resource>
```

,if not ,that would be 

`<resource><string>a</string><--comment--><string>b</string></resource>`

that make me confuse ,any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Why not just put the comment _before_ the element node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control how DOM formats the output beyond enabling/disabling it. You'd need to postprocess the XML as string, e.g. run the formatted output through `preg_replace`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement("resource"));
$root->appendChild($dom->createElement("string", "a"));
$root->appendChild($dom->createComment("comment here"));
$root->appendChild($dom->createElement("string", "b"));

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo preg_replace('#</string>\s+<!--#', "</string><!--", $dom->saveXML());
```

As pointed out by ThW in the comments: another option would be not to enable `formatOutput` and [add all the formatting you need through DOMNodes](https://eval.in/895282), e.g. add DOMText elements with whitespace. I find that somewhat ugly to do though, because they don't carry semantics and it will clutter the actual DOM construction.

But why do you need it formatted in this particular way? The formatting does not add any semantic meaning. It shouldn't matter whether the comment is next to the string element or below it.

Comment: the comment is closely  relevant to every single string tag。That would be nice for the manager to read and cut the line .

Comment: It is possible if you add the whitespace nodes manually - https://eval.in/895282 :-)

Comment: @ThW yes, but that's ugly. But I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's not fun, but you could build up your own formatter that way.